# Antipath in regard to a graph of transitive closure

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

I'm in the process of reading a paper that deals with graphs and their cliques. In the paper it uses graphs $G=(X,\Gamma)$ and their graph of transitive closure $G_t$. It then states:

> It is not worth while to distinguish between the graph of transitive closure $G_t$ and the partially ordered set $(X,>)$. Therefore in the graph $G_t$ we will also consider antipaths.

This makes some sense to me, but despite by best efforts I cannot find what an antipath is.

So, what is an antipath in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Chudnovsky](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/am-pdf/10.1002/jgt.22155), an antipath is:

> An *antipath* $Q$ in G is a sequence of distinct vertices $v_0- . . . -v_k$ where $v_i$ is non-adjacent to $v_j$ if
> and only if $|i − j| = 1$, and we call $k$ the *length* of the antipath

According to [Klimošová, Stein](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.09876), an antipath is:

> ...an oriented path (cycle, tree) where every
> vertex has either out-degree 0 or in-degree 0.